# Output result of xsl:value-of in an xml attribute

Tags: xslt

I have an XML input file and I'm trying to output the result of a call like:

```
<xsl:value-of select="Some/Value"/>
```

into an attribute.

```
<Output Attribute="Value should be put here"/>
```

My problem is, since I'm outputting XML, the XSL processor won't allow me to write:

```
<Output Attribute="<xsl:value-of select="Some/Value"/>">
```

How do you accomplish this?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [attribute value templates](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt.html#dt-attribute-value-template), like this:

```
<Output Attribute="{Some/Value}"/>
```

Comment: Doesn't work when Some/Value is an attribute? or am i wrong?

Comment: @Momo, if `Value` is an attribute of `Some` element, you should use `{Some/@Value}`

Answer (score 25):

You can use an xsl:attribute element:

```
<Output>
  <xsl:attribute name="Attribute">
    <xsl:value-of select="Some/Value"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</Output>
```